# Замена класса текущему элементу при нажатии

Tags: javascript

При клике на блок **main**, он должен поменять свой класс на **second,**

то есть должен поменяться размер шрифта и цвет фона.

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.main');

a.onclick = function(){
// код
}
```

```css
.main{
background:orange;
}


.second{
font-size:23px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class ="main">
Жил был кот и умер.
</div>
```

Comment: хоть немного бы погуглили)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let a = document.querySelector('.main');

a.onclick = function(){
a.classList.toggle('second');
}
```

```css
.main{
background:orange;
}


.second{
font-size:23px;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class ="main">
Жил был кот и умер.
</div>
```

Если не нужно переключать обратно по следующему клику - то

```
a.classList.remove('main');
a.classList.add('second');
```

Answer (score 1):

При помощи псевдокласса `:focus`.

Но для его работы с `<div>` необходимо добавить `tabindex="0"`, вот так:

```
<div class="ex" tabindex="0">Hello everyone</div>
```

```
.ex{
  background:orange;
}

.ex:focus{
  font-size:23px;
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]